# VB6 Winsock versus C# TcpListener

Tags: c#, sockets, winsock, telnet

I have written quite a few "listeners" in .NET (C#), specifically using the TcpListener class.  I have used both the `AcceptTcpClient` and `AcceptSocket` methods when a client connects, and  thus far have never really had any issues.

However, a current project revolves around re-writing a really old VB6 app in .NET.  It uses the Winsock Microsoft component.  It too is a TCP listener, however I have experienced something really odd that I'm not exactly sure how to duplicate in the C# code.

Run the VB6 app, and use Putty to connect to it. I don't know if you're familiar with Putty or not, but when connecting you can set it to a Raw client or a Telnet client.  This is important because if it's set to a telnet client, upon connection I type a single character in the terminal (no carriage return/linefeed), the `DataArrival` event on the Winsock component fires off, and I can use the GetData method to read the actual data.  When Putty is not using the Telnet option, instead setup as a Raw client, and I connect and type a single character, the DataArrival event of the Winsock component does not fire.  It does not fire until I press the ENTER key, then the DataArrival event fires.

So now I have a C# app, using `TcpListener`, and in Putty regardless if it's set to Raw or Telnet, I can never get any of the Read or Receive methods to get a single character until the enter key is actually pressed.

So can anyone tell me what is the difference between these two?  Why would the Winsock fire a DataArrival event upon a single keypress (no carriage return/line feed) only if the client is set in Telnet mode, but the C# code never gets that data until the enter key is pressed (carriage return/line feed).

I'm sure it has something to do with the difference in a telnet option versus a raw option, but regardless of what I try, the `Socket.Receive` or `TcpClient.NetworkStream.Read` will never ever pick up on that single character typed, while the Winsock component will.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can emulate this behaviour in straight up C# code, or at least can explain why the Winsock component behaves differently if the client is setup as Raw or Telnet?

Comment: The only thing I can think is that PuTTY is actively opting for "Local Line Editing" in one instance and not the other - http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.55/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#S4.3.8. Forcing Local Line Editing off seemed to stop the behavior for me (and my C# test program), but I can't imagine why it would disable this for the VB6 application only...

Comment: VisualMelon - That's exactly what it is.  There is an option in Putty for turning off the option for Local Line Editing.  Turning that off takes care of it, but as to why the VB6 app seems to do this, I'm not sure.  Perhaps the Winsock component does a specific negotiation that is isn't exposed thru the component itself?

Comment: It is rather interesting... I can't find anything anywhere suggesting that .NET should do anything differently to WinSocks, and I can't think what PuTTY could be basing it's decision to turn on Local Line Editing on.